# Eclipse 4.2 (Juno): Flatten search tree view similar to Package/Project Explorers?

Tags: eclipse, search, view, tree, flat

In both `Package Explorer` and `Project Explorer` there's the option to display flattened packages using e.g. `[More options arrow] -> Package Presentation -> Flat`.

Is there a similar option for the search pane when displaying results?

If you click `[Search pane] -> [More options arrow] -> Display as tree` then search, the results view within the `Search` pane displays each individual folder within the search path inside your project as a separate expandable/collapsible folder, and is unnecessarily space consuming visually and time consuming to navigate, in my opinion.

Sincere thanks.

Comment: it will automatically do that if you do a Java Search instead of a plain File Search.

Comment: nice one, thanks for the info. want to submit as an answer and i'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will automatically do that if you do a Java Search (or something that does a similar flattened style) instead of a plain File Search.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I tend to Ctrl+3, type 'File Search', press Enter then type-and-tab my way through the search form. Will attempt to familiarise myself with the more specific Java search parameters instead (and other language-specific tabs when need arises). Sincere thanks.